# EC2 Docker and internet connectivity

Tags: docker, amazon-ec2, node-red

I'm clutching at straws again! I have a docker container listening on port 1880. I can browse to it using curl to port 1880 on the local EC2 instance IP. I can ping 8.8.8.8 from inside the container. I can hit port 22 on the EC2 from the internet but not port 1880.

All the network acls are default any/any all ports at the moment.

When I run a tcpdump I see inbound ssh packets but nothing on 1880.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

You will need to open port 1880 in the AWS firewall, by default only port 22 is open so you can ssh in remotely.

The following document from Amazon will probably be helpful
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/authorizing-access-to-an-instance.html

Comment: Apologies for being an idiot. Thinking about there should be two levels of security I assumed the network acls would take care of it. Funny when I googled around I wasn't hitting anything mentioning security groups. Thanks